# truncated headers with SAS during proc import

Tags: sas

I'm having large headers for my columns like the one below (it is only a sample as I have 2000 columns with as many headers).

Each column is separated by a semi-colon.

```
BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,SEXL-SA,UK;BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,IBON-SA,TA;BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,TARO-SA,XR
1;7.2;3
35;8;0.99
```

I'm using the following command line in SAS to do the import

```
options macrogen symbolgen ;


PROC IMPORT OUT= Work.fic38_fic1 
        DATAFILE= "C:\cygwin\home\appEuro\pot\fic38.csv" 
        DBMS=DLM REPLACE;
 DELIMITER='3B'x;
 GETNAMES=YES;
 DATAROW=2;
 GUESSINGROWS=32767; 
RUN;

proc sort data=Work.fic38_fic1 ; by date ; run ;
```

However, for some unknown reasons, the headers got truncated.

```
BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,SEXL-SA;BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,IBON-SA;BAL_RT,ET-CAP,EXT_EA16,TARO-SA
```

I read the internet and they were talking about the option `LRCL`.

Does it make sense to anyone?

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is actually that you have 34-50 character wide variable names.  SAS has a maximum of 32 characters for variable names, so you will not be able to use the entire length in the variable name.  You may be able to use it as a variable *label*, but likely you would need to code that yourself if PROC IMPORT isn't going to do it for you.  You could take the code out of the log and use that code with the additional text added by hand if you like.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your feedback. This is the weird part because the header are about only 34 to 50 characters long. I'm not sure why SAS is not willing to use them as they are...

Comment: You said you have 2000 of them, though.  The default for PROC IMPORT is a lrecl of 32767, so 2000 * 50 = 100,000 which is well over that.

Comment: I said I have 2000 columns with around 34 to 50 characters-long for each headers ... Am I reading well ... ? OMG No ...

Comment: Are you confusing column with row?

Comment: I'm not confused, just crying my temporary hopelessness and frustration.

Please find my example below

`a*50TimesLong;b*50TimesLong;c*50TimesLong`
`1;2;3
4;5;6`

Comment: You are confusing columns with rows.

Comment: Let's say I'm confusing rows with columns. Do you have any solutions or insights that can help me ?

Comment: A row is something that goes from left to right, such as a row of text.  A column is top to bottom, in excel this would be the lettered A,B,C, etc.  You're describing column headers (so a*50itimeslong; is a column header).  Those cannot be over 32 in SAS, hence the truncation.  (They also can't have a lot of those characters in them.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and your help, Joe. I will need to find a way to deal with this. Cheers!

Comment: If you're trying to extract data from the headers, that wouldn't be difficult running this through your own data step.  Just don't try to run them through proc import, and don't try to use the whole thing as a variable name.  Feel free to post more details as to what's in the header to a new question.

Comment: Hi Joe, to give you an update, I talked to my boss. 

He found out a quite elegant solution. He put all the headers in a dictionary and put the name of the variable as `var_filenum_varnum` filenum for the number of the files and varnum for the number of the variables. Cheers.